# I am unable to configure/create a project with Specflow3 and VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, specflow

I am trying to create POM with specflow3 in VS2017. I have added below nuget packages. I am facing issues while setting up the project itself

1. Specflow.Nunit
2. Speclow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation
3. Specflow.NUnit.Testrunnen
4. Nunit test adapter plugin and specflow2017 plugin.

I have created a feature file and i am trying to build the solution. I am getting following error.

"Program doesnot contain a static main method suitable for an entry point." Kindly let me know the solution. It would be great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use specflow version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to create it as a console application. Change the project to be a class library, or start from a test project template.